# How to get response body and request header at the same time in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to use `HandlerInterceptor` to achive idempotent check, and if the request pass the intercepter, cache the response body which retrun from controller, and the key for cache is a token which from request header. but now, i can get request header(it contains the key for cache) in 'postHandle', but can't get response body(the value for cache) in this method. is there any way to achieve it?

here is my code:

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Idempotent {
}
```

```java
public class IdempotentInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Autowired
    private TokenService tokenService;
    @Autowired
    private RedisCache redisCache;
    @Value("${idempotent.tokenName}")
    private String TOKEN_NAME;
    @Value("${idempotent.respCachePrefix}")
    private String prefix;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (!(handler instanceof HandlerMethod)) {
            return true;
        }
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
        Idempotent methodAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Idempotent.class);
        if (methodAnnotation != null) {
            if (!tokenService.checkIdempotent(request)) {
                String token = request.getHeader(TOKEN_NAME);
                log.info("duplicate request, IdempotentToken: {}", token);
                Object result = redisCache.get(prefix + token);
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                if (result != null) {
                    log.info("{} exist result, return the cached result: {}", token, result);
                    response.getWriter().print(JSON.toJSONString(result));
                } else {
                    response.getWriter().print(JSON.toJSONString(new ResultDTO<>(ResultDTO.FAIL_CODE, "invalid request, please check idempotent token.")));
                }
                response.getWriter().flush();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        if (!(handler instanceof HandlerMethod)) {
            return;
        }
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
        Idempotent methodAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Idempotent.class);
        if (methodAnnotation != null) {
            // I want to cache the response body here, but can't get infos...
            redisCache.set(prefix + request.getHeader(TOKEN_NAME), "", 600L);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/test/{data}")
@Idempotent
public ResultDTO test(@PathVariable("data") String data) {
    return new ResultDTO(data);
}
```

in a word, i want to get both request headers and response body in one method

Comment: Implement this with a filter and not a `HandlerInterceptor`. Why because you need to wrap your response with a caching wrapper like the `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` from Spring so you can read the response twice.

Comment: You can use HttpServletResponse to get response headers.